# Does AUTO INCREMENT work when there are errors in MySQL?

Tags: mysql

I have been inserting data from an **HTML form** that **POST** the data to my server and then inserted into MySQL database.

I have successfully inserted into my database 3 times. BUT.. My id for each row that is an INT and that AUTO_INCREMENTS is showing something weird.

I have 3 rows, with an id of : 1, 2 , 10.

1 , 2 , 10?????

How did it go from 2 to 10?

Earlier I had been trying to insert data into the database that had the same email address. The email field is UNIQUE so it threw errors. It happened a few times and I didn't recognize it until I actually console logged the errors.

So my question is: Does my id AUTO_INCREMENT even when I have errors? Even though nothing was inserted successfully? or what is going on? and any other tips for a newcomer would be helpful!

Comment: so even though nothing was inserted successfully, it still auto increments? That doesn't make sense to me. Help a brother out with an explanation.

Comment: It's a trade-off for performance. Eliminating the gap would require inserts to hold some sort of lock on the sequence, lowering throughput.

Comment: You could read the docs? Auto-increment works like that on every RDBMS that i'm aware of.